# Assigning Kotlin var using subclass

Tags: kotlin

I have the following classes/interfaces:

```
interface A

interface Factory<in SpecType: Factory.Spec> {
    interface Spec
    fun create(spec: SpecType): A
}

class DefaultFactory : Factory<DefaultFactory.Spec> {
    data class Spec(
        val message: String
    ) : Factory.Spec

    override fun create(spec: Spec): A {
      // Do stuff here to create an instance of A using spec
    }
}
```

Then in another class I'd like to provide a default factory that can be replaced.

```
var factory: Factory<???> = DefaultFactory()
```

No matter what I seem to try and replace `???` with I can't get this to work well. I don't mind this crashing at runtime if a factory is used that accepts a `Spec` then gets passed a different one. The only thing I've found that works is:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
var factory: Factory<Factory.Spec> = DefaultFactory() as Factory<Factory.Spec>
```

But this just looks ugly and seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a type you can safely use for `???`: [`var factory: Factory<*>`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections). The only minor problem is that you can't pass anything to `create` (or rather, you can only pass `Nothing`).

This is because safe code doesn't allow

> crashing at runtime if a factory is used that accepts a Spec then gets passed a different one.

If you want it, you need an unsafe cast somewhere or a throw somewhere, and it *should* "look ugly and seem wrong".

This is somewhat better because it gives a useful exception:

```
inline fun <reified T : Factory.Spec> Factory<T>.upcast(): Factory<Factory.Spec> = 
    object : Factory<Factory.Spec> {
        override fun create(spec: Factory.Spec): A = 
            if (spec is T) 
                this.create(spec) 
            else throw IllegalArgumentException("Bad spec type, need ${T::class}")
    }

var factory: Factory<Factory.Spec> = DefaultFactory().upcast()
```

And if `create` returned `A?`, it could be made safe; just don't make it return `A?` only for this reason!

Answer (score 0):

Obvious answer will be `var factory:Factory<DefaultFactory.Spec> = DefaultFactory()`

---

But I think that you need something more sophisticated.

It's possible that in reality you need a provider interface like this:

```
interface Factory<in SpecType: Factory.Spec> {
    interface Spec
    fun create(spec: SpecType): A
    val spec: SpecType
}
```

And then your implementation will look like

```
class DefaultFactory : Factory<DefaultFactory.Spec> {
    override val spec: Spec
        get() = Spec("test message")
    override fun create(spec: Spec): A {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
    data class Spec(val message: String) : Factory.Spec
}
```

It looks perfectly valid for me, but it's impossible to solve your puzzle without details about your business. Why do you think you need generic there?

Comment: `val spec: SpecType` will disallow contravariance.